# Android Admob - Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

this is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/very_dark_gray"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivRefresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:onClick="ivRefresh_click"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
            android:src="@drawable/refresh_android96" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/fav"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/click_text_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivOpenShareLinks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivRefresh"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="openShareLinks"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
            android:src="@drawable/box_up96" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlMainArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llCurrentSong"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHrefStartStop"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5.07"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="playPause"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
                android:text="@string/start_stop"
                android:textColor="@color/click_items"
                android:textSize="@dimen/click_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSongName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="5.07"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/click_text_size" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbNowSong"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="5.07" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvArtist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="5.07"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlTopArea"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/llCurrentSong"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dip"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBackToMain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivBtnTopLIsten"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
                android:text="@string/listens"
                android:textColor="@color/click_items" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBtnTopLIsten"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:onClick="clickedTopSongsIcon"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_sort_by_size" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlEmail"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/email"
            android:onClick="clickContactUs"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/lower_image" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TableLayoutShare"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_white_no_radius_conrenrs"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivTwitter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/tw_icon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivFacebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/fb_icon" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/twitter"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/facebook"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_black_opacity_radius_corners" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutTodayPlaylist"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_black_opacity_only_half_radius_corners"
            android:onClick="openListenToday" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvListenThisWeak"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivLines1"
                android:onClick="openListenToday"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
                android:text="@string/was_today"
                android:textColor="@color/click_items" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLines1"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:onClick="clickedTopSongsIcon"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
                android:src="@drawable/lines" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_black_opacity_only_half_radius_corners"
            android:onClick="openListenThisWeek" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvListenToday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivLines1"
                android:onClick="openListenThisWeek"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
                android:text="@string/was_this_weak"
                android:textColor="@color/click_items" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLines1"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:onClick="clickedTopSongsIcon"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_menu_bar_items"
                android:src="@drawable/lines" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


     <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I added the google.service jar in this way:
moved the folder: google-play-services_lib
to the main app folder.

then, I entered eclipsed, and imported my app > right click on the app name > Properties >  Android > on the Libery Clicked 'Add' > added the Google play service:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dHrM.png

got the library in my project:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gEq6.jpg

when I'm trying to run my app, this error appear::

```
(26935): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.manishma/com.manishma.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #287: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
```

the unitID is checked (changed the code for the example).

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the 2 ways possible right now to display Admob ads. The first one is based on the Android SDK, the second one is based on Google Play services.

The difference between the 2 implementations are explained in details [in the developers documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration)

In my opinion Google Play services is still too buggy to be used, but soon this will be the only option left.

In your case you mix both because you are using the XML declarations from the Android SDK but at the same time you are integrating the Google Play Services library. You cannot use both, you need to choose one and follow the developer guide I gave above.

**Update**

1) If you want to use Google Play services, change your XML with this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

2) If you want to use the Android SDK, you have to add the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk jar in your libs folder and remove the Google Play services library.

**Those are not the only things to do, manifest files must for example also be updated (see documentation).**